How should I orientate an object with an uneven profile?
On a resin printer, if I have an object that is much broader at one end than the other - for example, a statue of a woman dress with a wide hooped bottom, or a statue of the Eiffel Tower with a wide base - and I am going to print it approximately horizontal (not perpendicular to the build plate). Reducing a 25-hour print to a 4.5-hour print, is it best to have the thin end towards the build plate with shorter supports, or towards the vat with longer supports?
Or, to describe it another way, should I orientate it so that the thin end prints first, or last?
